# Need help in finding nearest shift time in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have following table for shifts.

```
AutoId StartTime       EndTime
1      08:00:00 AM     04:00:00 PM
2      04:00:00 PM     12:00:00 AM
3      12:00:00 AM     08:00:00 AM
```

Now I want to assign Shifts to employees automatically..

For example, if someone comes 7:32 AM then his shift should be the first shift, that is, from 08:00:00 AM to 4:00:00 PM. If someone comes 11:45 PM then it should be automatically set as the third shift.

I also want that if an employee come in during the first hour of the shift then it should also work.

How do I find the nearest shift by giving employee InTime?

Comment: If an employee comes at 9:05 AM, what shift should be assigned to them? It's more than one hour in the first shift, but it's still very long before the next shift starts.

Comment: read my second comment that this is as per requirement....so that is not my question...if u know answer then just post here...otherwise no need to give any feedbacks...

Comment: Not sure what second comment you are talking about. You are saying that an employee should be granted 1 hour grace time. My question is, how to assign a shift if an empoyee clocks in when it's **more** than 1 hour into a certain shift but still too much time (like a couple of hours) before the next shift begins. I would just like to clarify that, and my example was 9:05 AM as the time when the employee clocks in.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
SELECT AutoId, StartTime, EndTime
  FROM Shifts
 WHERE StartTime = (SELECT MIN(StartTime) FROM Shifts WHERE DATEADD(hh, 1, StartTime) > inTime)
```

EDIT: Added grace period

Comment: it work for Intime is less than shift start time ...but what if some employee come after 15-20 mins...i want to give 1 hr grace period...

Comment: What if someone comes 30/55 minues late ?